# Dual booting Windows 11 and Ubuntu 22.04 LTS doesn't work

Tags: boot, dual-boot, 22.04, windows-11

## What's the problem?

I had installed Ubuntu yesterday, but I can boot it only through BIOS. I want to be able to boot it through the Windows dual boot menu.

## What have I tried to fix this?

I've typed random bcdedit commands that I've found on the internet, I tried figuring out what the problem is by using EasyBCD and Visual BCD, but I wasn't able to fix the problem.

I don't want to use the GRUB bootloader, because it doesn't look as good as the dual boot menu.

My installation ISO was `ubuntu-22.04.2-desktop-amd64.iso`.

Comment: Windows can not boot Ubuntu. It is not something that needs to be fixed. You use Grub if you want to have Windows and Ubuntu and choose the boot OS.

Comment: Since you are asking about using a Windows feature and using a Windows tool to work with it you may find the Windows Site a place to ask as well. Superuser.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will not work due to Windows only allowing a Windows dualboot.

I recommend using GRUB as a bootloader instead.